# Mysql: speed up query that contain a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table**:

```
id | date | id_device | total | others 15/20 columns
----------------------------------------------------
```

- can contains millions of records
- the table have an index for the columns **id_device** and **date**.
- it's a table where every minute X energy device saves its consumption (the total column. it is a value that is always increasing). But there could also be empty time intervals, as the table below.

I need to calculate the hourly consumption of a given device on a certain day of a specific interval hour.

To do this i have this query, **which works**.
example : 2018-10-03 , interval hour 00-01. This interval means (as well as all the others) to start from the last record before the 00 and finish to the last record of the 00. So, like the example above, the total of the 00 interval is 300-120, **300** (last record of 00) **120** (last record before the 00). *Subtraction is done in PHP.*

```
id | date                | id_device | total | others 15/20 columns
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 2018-10-02 23:50:20 | 1         | 100   | ....
2  | 2018-10-02 23:55:20 | 1         | 120   | ....
3  | 2018-10-03 00:01:20 | 1         | 150   | ....
.. | 2018-10-03 00:59:20 | 1         | 300   | ....
.. | 2018-10-03 01:00:20 | 1         | 350   | ....
```

---

```
SELECT `total` AS `total` FROM `mytable` AS `A`, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(`date`) AS `firstValue`, MAX(`date`) AS `lastValue`
        FROM `mytable`
        WHERE `date` BETWEEN 
        COALESCE((SELECT `date` FROM `mytable` WHERE `date` < '2018-10-03 00:00:00' AND `id_device` = 1 ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1), '2018-10-03 00:00:00'
        AND '2018-10-03 00:59:59'
        AND `id_device` = 1
    ) AS `B`

    WHERE `A`.`date` IN (`B`.`firstValue`,`B`.`lastValue`) AND `id_device` = 1
    ORDER BY `A`.`date`
```

---

With this query the execution time is about **0.9 / 1.5 seconds**. And it's too slow (i have to calculate this query X times, in a loop, for every single device).

Removing the subquery, the time of execution it's **practically 0**. The the time of execution is perfect, but the query in this way obviously does not suit me.

```
SELECT `total` AS `total` FROM `mytable` AS `A`, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(`date`) AS `firstValue`, MAX(`date`) AS `lastValue`
        FROM `mytable`
        WHERE `date` BETWEEN 
        '2018-10-03 00:00:00'
        AND '2018-10-03 00:59:59'
        AND `id_device` = 1
    ) AS `B`

    WHERE `A`.`date` IN (`B`.`firstValue`,`B`.`lastValue`) AND `id_device` = 1
    ORDER BY `A`.`date`
```

I tested the subquery individually and the time of execution it's **practically 0**.

```
SELECT `date` FROM `mytable` WHERE `date` < '2018-10-03 00:00:00' AND `id_device` = 1 ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1
```

So I can not understand why the original query is so slow.

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Incidentally, the query you've provided isn't valid, which makes a bit of a nonsense of your whole question.

Comment: The first query is not valid?

Comment: That one appears to be valid - but it's very clumsy. You do realise that `DATE_FORMAT('2018-10-03 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'` doesn't actually do anything useful, right?

Comment: Yes, but by copying the query to stackoverflow i took an older version that took the values in another way. Question updated

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can logically set a lower band for date (for example 5 days ago or 30 days ago, depend on your problem) in

```
SELECT `date` FROM `mytable` WHERE `date` < DATE_FORMAT('2018-10-03 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND `id_device` = 1 ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1
```

can get response in a in reasonable time

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the hierarchy of queries (make the outer one into the sub-query), or better still use a join.
Try (here comes captain obvious) to use indexed fields if possible when joining and filtering.
Set dates for `where` in variables and use the variables instead of dateformat. Otherwise it will actually be calculated for each row, and that can slow down the query considerably.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by moving the subquery to a `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT `total` AS `total`
FROM `mytable` AS `A`CROSS JOIN 
     (SELECT MIN(t2.`date`) AS `firstValue`, MAX(t2.`date`) AS `lastValue`
      FROM `mytable` t2 CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT t3.`date`
            FROM `mytable` t3
            WHERE t3.`date` < '2018-10-03' AND t3.`id_device` = 1
            ORDER BY t3.`date` DESC
            LIMIT 1
           ) d
      WHERE t2.date >= COALESCE(d.date, '2018-10-03') AND
            t2.date < '2018-10-04' AND
            t2.id_device = 1
    ) B
WHERE `A`.`date` IN (B.firstValue, B.lastValue) AND
      A.`id_device` = 1
ORDER BY `A`.`date`;
```

For this query, I would start with an index on `mytable(id_device, date)`.

I would suggest indexes as well, but you state that the base queries run quickly.  So, additional indexes are not needed.

You can probably also simplify the logic using `union all`.

Comment: @WhiteLine . . . Column references should always be qualified.

Comment: Yes now it's ok, but the query has been detected still slow .. 1.4 - 2 seconds